# Meaning of superscript letters in sidereal time calculation

Tags: orbital-mechanics, celestial-mechanics, sgp4

I'm following along with [Dr Kelso's columns on CelesTrack](http://celestrak.org/columns/v02n01/) and I've come across this equation.

$$θ_g(0^h)=24110^s.54841+8640184^s.812866T_u+0^s.093104T_u^2- 6.2\times10^{-6} T_u^3$$

As you can see, there are superscript $^s$s right before the decimal point on some of these values and a superscript $^h$s next to the 0 argument in the function definition.

What do these signify? Is it the unit of the terms? If so, it's weird notation I've never seen before.

Comment: The " Explanatory Supplement to the Astronomical Almanac" is available here  https://archive.org/details/131123ExplanatorySupplementAstronomicalAlmanac/page/n39/mode/1up where you can read the page 50 reference. The whole "Time" chapter seems to use that notation for days, hours, minutes, seconds. See page 41.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Do you want to write that up as an answer or should I?

Comment: Go for it, not my wheelhouse.

Comment: FYI StackExchange supports [LaTeX](https://space.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) markup via MathJax, which you could use instead of the inline image.

Comment: @ErinAnne - Ahh, I thought that was only enabled for Math.SE

Comment: @ErinAnne Some but not all parts of StackExchange support MathJax markup. The parts associated with science, technology, engineering, and math (STEM) tend to do so. The  non-STEM parts tend not to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $$θ_g(0^h)=24110^s.54841+8640184^s.812866T_u+0^s.093104T_u^2- 6.2\times10^{-6} T_u^3$$

> What do these superscript "s"s signify? Is it the unit of the terms?

In this expression, the superscript "s" represents mean hour angle sidereal seconds. This is a measure of angle. There are 24 hour angles in a 360° rotation, so 24*60=1440 hour angle minutes in a 360° rotation and 24*60*60=86400 hour angle seconds in a 360° rotation. Hour angle is handy way of representing rotation because it corresponds nicely with time. Just as there are 86400 UT1 seconds in a mean solar day, there are 86400 mean sidereal seconds in a sidereal day.

Note that the referenced expression is valid at midnight UT1 only as the expression omits the 360° (or 86400 hour angle seconds) that the Earth rotates through per day.

Comment: To convert hour angle seconds to arcseconds, multiply by 15. To convert  hour angle seconds to degrees, divide by 240.

Comment: It's really weird how it's put before the decimal point rather than after the number

Comment: @ScottishTapWater This is fairly common in astronomy. For example 123.456 degrees will oftentimes be marked as $123^\circ.456$ as opposed to $123.456^\circ$.

Comment: How strange... Although I must say, it's actually arguably less ambiguous because there's no chance of confusing units with algebraic terms